# Get the nth word of a line

Tags: c#, regex

With this code:

```
regex = new Regex(@"^(?:\S+\s){2}(\S+)");
match = regex.Match("one two three four five");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

I want to retrieve the third word of the line --> "three".
But instead, I get "one two three".

Edit:
I know that I could do it with `s.Split(' ')[2]` but I want to do it with regex.

Comment: `(?<=^(\S+\s){2})(\S+)`

Comment: Not sure what language this is, but can't you access a specific group in the match instead of the entire match?

Comment: @tobias_k in .Net it is supported

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov could you post this as an answer please?

Comment: Instead of regexing, you might be able to split the string on whitespace and return value at index 2?

Comment: @joppich I know this solution, but I want to train my regex skills. ;)

Comment: @kame this is the wrong "lesson" for regex skills then, this would _always_ be solved using `Split()` in the real world, why not find an actual use case for Regex to practice?

Comment: Agree with @maccettura, I would use `.Split(' ').ElementAt(2)`. I think a good lesson would be to only use Regex when necessary.

Comment: Should I delete this question then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `Match` method only without reference to groups, etc., then you have to use look-behind. Basically you say - find a word that is preceded by two words. In you current regex you say - find me 2 words + 1 word, so you just have to change part "find 2 words" to "preceded by 2 words", i.e. `^(?:\S+\s){2}` is changed to `(?<=^(\S+\s){2})`

```
(?<=^(\S+\s){2})\S+
```

Comment: What does `?<=^` stand for?

Comment: `(?<=...)` - positive look-behind. `^` - beginning of string.

Answer (score 2):

`match.Value` returns the entire matched substring, which includes the non-capturing parts of your regex. You should instead use `match.Groups[1].Value` to get the value of the first capturing group.